# What is the 'March Preset' and the 'March Preset Update'?

Tags: game-of-war-fire-age

In *Game of War: Fire Age* **What is the 'March Preset' and the 'March Preset Update'?**

What is it for, and how do I use it? I've tried clicking on it and nothing happens.

Comment: I don't know the game, but a quick search on Google revealed that it's used to save the amount of each soldier type in a 'march', and the update button allows you to update that preset accordingly.